# Store multiple tasks for a job in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing an application using Ruby on Rails 4 that has a list of pre-defined tasks that can be added into a job. The job can have one or more tasks assigned to it. How do I store the tasks in the job object? Would this be through an array of some sort? What would that look like?

I imagine this would work like a [tokenfield](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/) or even a selectable list. Maybe checkboxes (but that may get unwieldy).

**app/models/job.rb**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  has_many :tasks
end
```

**app/models/task.rb**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  belongs_to :job
end
```

**Tasks Table** - *just a sample*

```
id |   name     |   description
 1 | Clean Room | Pick up toys
 2 | Dust Shelf | Use dusting rag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you need to be able to assign the same task to multiple jobs. This will mean either a `has_many :tasks` or a `has_many :tasks, through: :task_assignments` association on the `Job` model. If you need further guidance on using these associations, have a look at [the Rails Guides Association Basics guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

As for the controller and view components, I suggest you have a look at [the Rails Guides Form Helpers guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), and perhaps also watch Railscasts episodes on handlign nested forms: [#196 - Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [#197 - Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2).

Comment: Ah, yes, should have clarified this. A task can be assigned to multiple jobs. So I should have a `has_many :tasks, through: :task_assignments` association. This looks like exactly what I need. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries @samurailink3, though don't forget to also create the `TaskAssignment` model and associations.